# Apache RewriteRule - send url with querystring to one without

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a legacy URL which it seems a lot of users have bookmarked and it looks something like:

`www.mydomain.com/dir/?info=mystuff`

I would like this to show the following:

`www.mydomain.com/mystuff.php`

I've tried this in the htaccess but no joy:

```
RewriteRule ^dir/?info=([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**EDIT:**

Here's all my htaccess file incase it matters or anything else is causing a clash.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dir/list/?$ /downloads/list.pdf [L,QSA]

# THIS DOESN'T WORK...
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} info=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/dir\/?$ /%1.php? [L]

RewriteRule ^dir/([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]


AddType application/octet-stream .pdf

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: If you open `www.mydomain.com/mystuff.php` in browser, does it show the right content?

Comment: Yes it does... what are you thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} info=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/dir\/?$ /%1.php? [L]
```

Comment: Hmmmm, still not working... I've added all my htaccess code since it's not huge. Any ideas?

Comment: You would need to put it above the `RewriteRule ^dir/([^/]+)/?$` rule

Comment: OK, I see what you mean but I think the line `RewriteRule ^/dir\/?$ /%1.php? [L]` is causing a problem too because `mydomain.com/dir` is a valid URL and it's showing that (which is really `mydomain.com/dir.php`)

Comment: Yes but you have the `RewriteCond`, so it will only run when `info=something` is present in the query string

Comment: OK, so I've edited the code to show what I have now, but I can't see why it's not working...

Comment: It was the leading slash before `dir` that was causing the problem... all sorted thanks!

Comment: Well spotted! Glad I could help.